# How to connect to remote oracle database using typeorm in nestjs?

Tags: oracle, nestjs, typeorm, dbconnection

I was wondering how to connect to remote oracle database from nestjs using typeorm.
I installed typeorm and oracle package using following command.

npm i --save @nestjs/typeorm typeorm oracle

npm install oracledb --save

and then tried configuring in app.module.ts using TypeOrmModule.forRoot but it was not succesfull.

Here are my configuration settings.

TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
type: 'oracle',
host: 'ip of hostname',
port: port number,
username: 'username',
password: 'password',
serviceName: 'servicename',
synchronize: false,
entities: []
})

Can anybody help me out what am I missing? Also would like to know how can I execute the query once this connection is succesfully? If any example that would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

one missing thing was database name.
Added

database: 'databasename' in above configuration and it worked.

But, still my question is how to use this connection in service to fetch/push the data from/to oracle databse?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a name in your connection details you should be able to refer to the database connection using that. Otherwise, if no name is provided I believe it assigns it the name 'default'.

Basically these are the steps you should perform to use the database connection: (examples below each)

1. Create a model - this is how TypeORM knows to create a table.

```
export class Photo {
    id: number
    name: string
    description: string
    filename: string
    views: number
    isPublished: boolean
}
```

2. Create an Entity. - this should match your model, with the appropriate decorators. At minimum you should have the @Entity() decorator before your class definition and @Column() before each field.

```
import { Entity, Column } from "typeorm"

@Entity()
export class Photo {
    @Column()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @Column()
    description: string

    @Column()
    filename: string

    @Column()
    views: number

    @Column()
    isPublished: boolean
}
```

3. Create your data source - looks like you have already done this. But I would give it a name field and you will need to pass your entities into the entity array you have.

```
const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    name: "photos",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "root",
    password: "admin",
    database: "test",
    entities: [Photo],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
})
```

4. Then you can use repositories to manage data in the database:

```
const photo = new Photo()
photo.name = "Me and Bears"
photo.description = "I am near polar bears"
photo.filename = "photo-with-bears.jpg"
photo.views = 1
photo.isPublished = true

const photoRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Photo)

await photoRepository.save(photo)
console.log("Photo has been saved")

const savedPhotos = await photoRepository.find()
console.log("All photos from the db: ", savedPhotos)
```

For more details I would spend some time reading through the typeORM website, all the examples I pulled were from there:
https://typeorm.io/